# eclipse doxygen excluding part of the path name

Tags: eclipse, doxygen

I'm using Eclipse and Doxygen on a Linux platform. My teams code is controlled with Clearcase.  My question is can I use an environment variable as part of the path to excluded?

example:  every one on the project has a custom view as part of their path. And I don't want to see that in the documentation.

```
    /view/me/a/b/src/.../...
    /view/you/a/b/src/.../...
```

in each developers view their is an environment variable defined with their view name.    ex: $CLEARCASE_ROOT = /view/me

So I'm trying to setup a single Doxygen file for whole team to use..

So I want to do something like  EXCLUDE ${CLEARCASE_ROOT}/a/b

Then everybody that generates docs will get the same paths..  Can I do this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, doxygen supports environment variable expansion in its configuration files, see http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html.

The `EXCLUDE` option controls which files are parsed by doxygen. It sounds like you want the files to be included, but you want them to be displayed with a relative include path, in that case you probably want to use the `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` option. If there are other absolute paths in the documentation you're attempting to make relative, the `STRIP_FROM_PATH` option may also come into play.

The syntax is a little different than what you proposed, `$()` vs. `${}`, so you'll want to specify something like:

```
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH = $(CLEARCASE_ROOT)/a/b
STRIP_FROM_PATH = $(CLEARCASE_ROOT)
```